# HABTM 3 deep nested

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

**ERROR :unknown attribute: size_id**

**Item Model**

```
has_many :sizeables
has_many :sizes, through: :sizeables, :dependent => :destroy

accepts_nested_attributes_for :sizes,  :reject_if => lambda { |a| a.values.all?(&:blank?) }, :allow_destroy => true
```

**Size Model**

```
has_many :sizeables
has_many :items, through: :sizeables

has_one :centimeter
accepts_nested_attributes_for :centimeter,  allow_destroy: true
```

**Centimeter Model**

```
belongs_to :size
```

**Item Controller**

```
def new 
    @item = Item.new
    @size = @item.sizes.build
    @size.build_centimeter  
end
```

**Item New View**

```
<%= f.fields_for :sizes do |s| %>
<%= s.fields_for :centimeter do |c| %>
<%= c.text_field :height %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

**ERROR :unknown attribute: size_id**

Comment: Does your `Item` model `accept_nested_attributes_for :sizes`? I don't see it.

Comment: yes, sorry i'll correct my answer!